# Azure Functions: Cannot apply attribute class 'Queue<T>' because it is generic

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I'm using Visual Studio Code to develop an Azure Durable Function, following some online examples.  I'm completely new to Azure and adapting to C# from VB.NET.  I already developed a working durable function that stores data in a blob table.  This is a slight adaptation of that which aims to put the information into a queue.

I'm following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-add-output-binding-storage-queue-vs-code?pivots=programming-language-csharp), and have code that I think should work, except that it tells me this:

`Cannot apply attribute class 'Queue<T>' because it is generic`

However I've looked at some other examples, including the one from Microsoft, and don't anything special being done for typing of queue.  Clearly, though, I'm missing something.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Test.Groove
{
    public static class GrooveWebhook
    {
        [FunctionName("GrooveWebhook")]
        public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
        {
            var outputs = new List<string>();
            GrooveItem data = context.GetInput<GrooveItem>();  
            string res = await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("AddToQueue", data);
            return outputs;
        }
        
        [FunctionName("AddToQueue")]
        public static async Task<String> Run(
            [ActivityTrigger] GrooveItem trans, 
            [Queue("incoming-groove-webhooks")] IAsyncCollector<GrooveItem> GrooveData, 
            ILogger log)
        {
            await GrooveData.AddAsync (trans);
            return $"Added Groove transaction for {trans.firstname} {trans.lastname}: {trans.email}";
        }

        [FunctionName("GrooveWebhook_HttpStart")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpStart(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestMessage req,
            [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
            ILogger log)
        {
            // Function input comes from the request content.
            var data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<GrooveItem>();
            string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("GrooveWebhook", data);
            log.LogInformation($"Started Groove webhook orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");
            return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, here's the **really weird** part.  I followed along literally step by step with their http trigger example, code as follows, and yet don't have that same error:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace My.Functions
{
    public static class HttpExample
    {
        [FunctionName("HttpExample")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            [Queue("outqueue"),StorageAccount("AzureWebJobsStorage")] ICollector<string> msg,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string name = req.Query["name"];

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
                ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
                : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

So then, as if that wasn't weird enough, I went back to my original project that added data to a table, and just added this little queue binding statement, and I don't have the error!  This is so crazy.  Code begins:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Company.Function
{
    public static class GrooveOrchestrationTest
    {
        [FunctionName("GrooveOrchestrationTest")]
        public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context,
            [Table ("GrooveData")] IAsyncCollector<GrooveItem> GrooveData,
            [Queue ("GrooveQueue")] IAsyncCollector<GrooveItem> GrooveQueue)
```

There are no additional `using` directives in either of the latter solutions that successfully bind the queue for output.

**One Additional Thought**
I created another version from scratch with the exact same problem, even though my other one is still fine.  I have no explanation for this.  However, I will note that they are connected to DIFFERENT Azure accounts.  Both are on the free tier, both just signed up in the last couple of days.  I can't fathom why that should matter, but it's all I can think of.

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow. Please remove insignificant code and add meaning title to your question. Read more here and please not be offended https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: The problem is that `Queue` is resolved to `System.Collections.Generic.Queue<T>` and not to the `QueueAtttribute` that Azure defines. (The sample that doesn't give an error isn't using `System.Collections.Generic`.) This *should* mean that Azure's `QueueAttribute` is not in scope, because the compiler's supposed to give an error if an attribute reference is ambiguous (although the priority of this check might be lower than the check for genericity). See if you get an error if you use `QueueAttribute` explicitly for a missing namespace (or else the code might just compile rightaway).

Comment: I had the same thought, which got me to looking at what as happening behind the scenes and discovered it was a difference in a reference added by VS Code.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is caused by the following reference added automatically by VS Code into the .csproj file:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.7" />
```

This is confirmed by changing it to match the reference from the other solution where the exact same code works perfectly:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.3" />
```

With this change in reference, it works as expected.

What lead me to this is the fact that my queue binding worked fine when pasted into my older solution from just a few days ago, but the exact same code didn't work in the new solution.  To ensure all things were equal, I pasted the entire contents of the .cs file so there would be no difference.  I.e. the old solution and the new one had identical .cs files, but one worked and one didn't.

Since my code was identical in both solutions, it seemed clear that there must be something that VS Code had done behind the scenes.  I did a stare-and-compare on all its automatically generated files between the old solution and the new one.  I discovered that this one reference is literally the **only** difference between the two solutions, and when I change it to the older version, things work beautifully.

I'll reference the older package for now so I can get this done, and then when I get some free time figure out how to make the new SDK.Functions happy.

Answer (score 1):

You might be lacking reference to `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage`.

Comment: That's a good observation.  This now works (without that reference) though - the problem was an issue with a particular SDK version level.  Although I don't have the specific reference you mention, I do have `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Queue` which is what it actually needs.